# Add new property to an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have a list of entities where each entity is as follows:

```
var entity = {
  position: 'X',
  varA: [{ id: 1, name: 'A1' }, { id: 2, name: 'A2' }],
  varB: [{ id: 1, name: 'B1' }, { id: 2, name: 'B2' }],
  varC: [{ id: 1, name: 'C1' }, { id: 2, name: 'C2' }],
}
```

For each entity I need to add a property 'names' that is:

```
entity.names = [varA[0].name, varB[0].name, varC[0].name];
```

The problem is that varA, varB or varC can in some cases be undefined or have no values. So I tried:

```
vm.entities.map(function(entity) { 

  entity.names = [entity.varA[0], entity.varB[0], entity.varC[0]].filter(e => e).map(({name:n}) => n);

  return entity; 

});
```

The expected output is:

```
entity.names = [ 'A1', 'B1', 'C1' ]
```

However, I am unable to minify my javascript due to this code line:

```
entity.names = [entity.varA[0], entity.varB[0], entity.varC[0]].filter(e => e).map(({name:n}) => n);
```

What am I doing wrong and is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Did you try checking if your variables are undefined before ? `entity.names = [entity.varA[0] ? entity.varA[0] : null, entity.varB[0] ? entity.varB[0] : null, entity.varC[0] ? entity.varC[0] : null]`

Comment: why do you use hardcoded keys instead of computed ones? E.G. `entity[/*expr*/]` instead of `entity.varA`?

Comment: @Adelin it really doesn't matter ...

Comment: @AnteJablanAdamović I think you prematurely said that. What if OP has thousands of `varA`, `varB`, `varC`?

Comment: From his post I'd assume he only has those 3 hardcoded values, if he has `n` possible properties then `entity[/*expr*/]` combined with `Object.keys` is the way to go yes.

Comment: Uglify.js does not support ES6, so you need to do your code in ES5.

Comment: @Zenoo I was trying to keep my code short as I might have more then 3 variables.

Comment: @Adelin because the API I am calling is returning it that way.

Comment: @connexo, can you clarify what I need to change in my code?

Comment: You need to replace your arrow function with a standard ES5 `function()`.

Comment: @connexo you mean the part ".filter(e => e).map(({name:n}) => n);", correct? I tried a few options but wasn't able to make it work. I am probably missing something. Could you, please, post your code? Thank you.

Comment: @connexo I think I got it. It is the following: .filter(function(x) { return x; }).map(function(x) { return x.name; });

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate all keys of the object and take only arrays for collecting names for the new property.

For getting only one name out of the array, you could use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and exit if a name of an array is found.

```js
var entity = { position: 'X', varA: [{ id: 1, name: 'A1' }, { id: 2, name: 'A2' }], varB: [{ id: 1, name: 'B1' }, { id: 2, name: 'B2' }], varC: [{ id: 1, name: 'C1' }, { id: 2, name: 'C2' }] };

entity.names = Object.keys(entity).reduce(function (r, k) {
    if (Array.isArray(entity[k])) {
        entity[k].some(function (o) {
            if (o && typeof o === 'object' && o.name) {
                r.push(o.name);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
    return r;
}, []);

console.log(entity);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: What if `o` is a function? It too has a `name` property

Comment: the data does not look like this, but you could add a check for `typeof o !== 'function`' if required.

Comment: I only need the first name of each var not all. And if each var has 40 names I would go through all them to get only the first one.